# Cannot find @angular/fire/firestore module error in VScode

Tags: angular, firebase, module, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to firebase firestore. 
And this is my first project with firestore.
I installed angular fire with this command

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
```

and now importing the angularfiremodule like this

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
```

and angularfirestoremodule like this

```
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

But this is giving me error

> Cannot find module '@angular/fire'.ts(2307)

Any idea what might be the error?
I tried google searching but since I am new to firebase, everything seems very mixed up to me. 
Also, I'm using ionic version 4, Angular version 8.1.3 and node version 10.16.3 if that makes any difference.

Angularfire2 was working fine previously, but since it's deprecated, I want to move to angular/fire.

Answer (score 10):

I solved the problem by using below import statement, in `app.module.ts`

```
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore/';
```

Answer (score 3):

My problem solved by using import like this which i have mentioned below with firebase version 9 and firestore 7 and angular 12.

As per the offical document

[Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y73hm.png)

Got reference from this link:
https://dev.to/jdgamble555/angular-12-with-firebase-9-49a0

For official reference check this out:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Install firestore by using

**ng add @angular/fire**

Install firebase by using

**npm install firebase**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';        
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';        
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';        
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';        
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';        
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';        
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';        
import { getStorage, provideStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';        
import { getAnalytics, provideAnalytics } from '@angular/fire/analytics';        

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';               

@NgModule({
  declarations: [        
    AppComponent,        
    DashboardComponent,       
    ForgotPasswordComponent,        
    SignInComponent,      
    SignUpComponent,  
    VerifyEmailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),     
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),  
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),  
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),  
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),  
    BrowserModule,  
    AppRoutingModule  
  ],  
  providers: [],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]  
 })    
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's some version mismatch issue here.

Here's what you might want to do in order to make this work.

**DISCLAIMER: I'll be using StackBlitz for Demo Purposes.**

Steps to follow:

1. Navigate to the [**StackBlitz Template**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1iment) Link mentioned in the [**Quick Links section**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire#quick-links) of @angular/fire GitHub README.
2. Try importing `AngularFirestoreModule` in the `AppModule` and add it to the imports `array`.

   ```
   import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
   ```
3. Go to your `AppComponent` and import `AngularFirestore` and inject it as a dependency:

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
   import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
   })
   export class AppComponent  {
     items: Observable<any[]>;
     constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
       this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
     }
   }
   ```
4. You'll get an error saying:

   > ERROR Error: app.firestore is not a function
5. You would like to do a Google search finding the reason and a probable fix for the issue. You'll probably end up on [**this GitHub thread**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1880) which would suggest that you reinstall the dependencies.
6. Since we are on StackBlitz, you'll just press the **"Update all deps to latest"** button in the DEPENDENCIES section. As soon as you do that, you'll start getting an error saying:

   > Can't find package:core-js
7. It's apparently a known issue for StackBlitz. In order to fix it, you'll do a Google search again and probably end up on [**this GitHub thread**](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/930).
8. As suggested in the thread, you'll install `core-js@2` by adding it to the DEPENDENCIES Field and pressing enter. This will install Version 2.6.11 of `core-js`.
9. Now you'll get an error saying:

   > Can't find package:@firebase/app

   To fix it, you'll just click on the blue button that says **"INSTALL PACKAGE `@firebase/app`"**
10. Finally, you'll get an error saying:

    > ERROR Error: `"projectId"` not provided in firebase.initializeApp.

    To fix this, just paste in your `firebase` config.

And hopefully, after following all these steps, you should be able to see the project updated to `@angular/fire`.

> Here's a [**Working Demo till Step 9**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-project-updated-to-latest-angular-fire-version?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts) to save some of your time.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Umm you gave the demo using StackBlitz, but since I am on VSCode I don't have the buttons to update dependencies etc.

Comment: For that, you might just want to delete your `package-lock.json` file and re-run `npm i`

Comment: is there any update? I am using version 10 of angular but still the problem persist getting this error This likely means that the library (@angular/fire/firestore) which declares AngularFirestore has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if 
the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Answer (score 1):

In app.module.ts add this

```
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

In your file import AngularFireStore as

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
```

Answer (score 0):

With new angualr-firebase version (v7.5.0), the following code will work :

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, getApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({ ... })),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and

```
import { Firestore, collectionData, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

interface Item {
  name: string,
  ...
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of item$ | async">
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  item$: Observable<Item[]>;
  constructor(firestore: Firestore) {
    const collection = collection(firestore, 'items');
    this.item$ = collectionData(collection);
  }
}
```

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire